# Configuring postgreSQL in play framework Scala

Tags: postgresql, playframework-2.0

How can I configure the postgresql to play framework in java i already downloaded the postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar file.

Thank you!

Comment: are you using Eclipse or any other IDE.? or you work without IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit "build.sbt" file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc41"
)
```

See also http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#managed-dependencies